# It is hard for me to understand the difference between Idle and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-idle

If I put a simple code like

> 3 == 3

On Pycharm I can see it's 'true' or 'false' but on Idle it shows true.

And I cant understand the difference between Idle and Pycharm

On pycharm

```sh
"D:\PHYTHON PROJECT\venv\Scripts\python.exe" C:/Users/UQO/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/practice.py
```

Process finished with exit code 0

On Idle

```py
>>> 3==3
True
```

Comment: Pycharm and Idle are both sowtware built to help writing Python code, they are expected to run the same code without difference. So ih they both provide the same output for the same code, everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the python's shell immediately prints the result of previous operation. But if you want to print something in your script you have to do it explicitly by control your output.

Try this

```py
print(3 == 3)
```